# changing commerce product price but also components!

Tags: commerce

When I ask price info of a product, i have this:

```
Array (
    [amount] => 3020
    [currency_code] => EUR
    [data] => Array
        (
            [include_tax] => 21_btw
            [components] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => base_price
                            [price] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => 2496
                                    [currency_code] => EUR
                                    [data] => Array
                                        (

                                    )

                            )

                        [included] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => tax|21_btw
                        [price] => Array
                            (
                                [amount] => 524
                                [currency_code] => EUR
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [tax_rate] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => 21_btw
                                                [display_title] => 21% BTW
                                                [description] => 21% BTW
                                                [rate] => 0.21
                                                [type] => vat
                                                [rules_component] => commerce_tax_rate_21_btw
                                                [default_rules_component] => 1
                                                [price_component] => tax|21_btw
                                                [calculation_callback] => commerce_tax_rate_calculate
                                                [module] => commerce_tax_ui
                                                [title] => 21% BTW
                                                [admin_list] => 1
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [included] => 1
                    )

            )

    )
```

so then i have price with components, then I have this snippet of code to update price, with new price:

```
            $product_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $product);
            $product_wrapper->commerce_price->amount=30200;
            $product_wrapper->save();
```

but this updates the price, and then I loose the components, I do not understand, isn't there a way to update the price and the components with just one method, or does someone know howto update price and components, what do I have to change in the code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're entering your product prices with VAT included. This is a feature of the Tax module that works through the product add / edit form to manipulate the product price on form submission. There is no separate API function for it, though that would be a mighty fine feature request if you'd like to open it. Instead you just need to replicate what the module does.

The way it works is that it actually just stores the name of the tax rate in the price's data array via the "include_tax" key. You can see this in the function commerce_tax_price_field_validate(). The tax price component then is actually calculated on load via hook_field_attach_load(). This means you shouldn't need to create the tax price component, just ensure the data array contains the target tax rate and that the price is "reloaded" to recalculate that price component.